# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig' but swig is already imported

Tags: python, installation, swig

I'm setting up my virtual environment right now and I'm trying to install faiss-cpu. The problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
\`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /scratch1/skzhang/NNK_params/nnk_param_env/bin/python3 /scratch1/skzhang/NNK_params/nnk_param_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/pep517/
in_process/\_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpffzso5pd
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wd2v3dbd/faiss-cpu_83e2fb8a63d342bf9619c47cf685b0c7
Complete output (12 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'faiss.\_swigfaiss' extension
swigging faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss.i to faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss_wrap.cpp
swig -python -c++ -Doverride= -I/usr/local/include -Ifaiss -doxygen -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -module swigfaiss -o faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss_wrap.cpp faiss/faiss/p
ython/swigfaiss.i
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/scratch1/skzhang/NNK_params/nnk_param_env/bin/swig", line 5, in \<module\>
from swig import swig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
-

ERROR: Failed building wheel for faiss-cpu
ERROR: Could not build wheels for faiss-cpu, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects\`
```

I ran `pip3 install swig --upgrade` already that that went successfully. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling but still nothing. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Also I'm using python 3.6.8 if that's useful at all. Thanks!

Comment: oh the formatting is off... welcome anyway!

Comment: you can try to install - `pip install faiss-cpu`

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi Hi, thanks for the input. I get the error mentioned above when I run that command

Comment: I believe there is compatibility issue, try to upgrade - `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and then install `faiss-cpu`

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi It still doesn't work. I was reading some posts and do you think it could be due to having multiple versions of python in my bin? When I run `ls /bin/python*` I get `bin/python  /bin/python2  /bin/python2.7  /bin/python3  /bin/python3.6  /bin/python3.6m`. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that might be the issue unless you have a specified version of python added in PATH variable and you are working on that python version and its virtual env respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Ok update is that it's working now. I think there was something wrong with the virtual environment I set up because after I stopped using it faiss-cpu seems to install without a problem. Not exactly sure what I was doing wrong earlier though.